# Powershell certificate authentication on standalone server?

Tags: powershell, ssl, certificate

I've tried searching for a solution to this for half a day and decided I need to ask the question myself.

My goal is to remotely control standalone Windows servers via PowerShell on our internal network. Our environment is based on MicroFocus eDirectory instead of MS Active Directory so our servers are not connected via GPOs.

Since PowerShell have existed for such a long time and you can control commandline only installs via this I assumed there would be a solution in a form of certificate authentication client to server but I've yet to find anything resembling this.

I'm aware of workarounds including creating private keys to store decrypt in scripts but we do not want to risk losing such information and wish to be able to create certificates to both new clients and servers without having to include any form of credentials in scripts.

Is there no way to simply use certificates to authenticate in place of credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this chapter in PS remoting book, it describes exactly what you need. https://devopscollective.gitbooks.io/secrets-of-powershell-remoting/content/manuscript/accessing-remote-computers.html

The certificate auth part starts in the middle somewhere, look for "Certificate Authentication"

Comment: Thank you very much for this!  
<br/>
Looks like what I need, albeit a massive intake of information but eventually it looks like this should provide us with what we need.
I wish Windows would integrate security in their PowerShell arsenal considering how it is required to use for non-gui installations and we don't want "easy fixes" that also removes our security in mutual authentication.

Comment: they are moving that, way trust me. there are a lot of improvements in security in posh 5 and upwards.